# Issue in Histogram Plotting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I'm trying to plot histogram of sample data available in lubridate package in R. The following code i'm using to create a histogram  but i'm getting an error for duration which states: **Incompatible duration classes (Duration, numeric). Please coerce with *as.duration*.** Could anyone tell what is the issue here?

```
library("lubridate")
library("ggplot2")
str(lakers$time)
lakers$time<-ms(lakers$time)
lakers$time <- as.duration(lakers$time)
lakers$time <-dminutes(c(12, 24, 36, 48, 53)[lakers$period]) - lakers$time
qplot(time, data=lakers, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 60)
```

**Link to Histogram Output:**
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256779/issue-in-histogram-plotting-in-r

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik i have updated the question ..you can find the link to the histogram that should be the output

Comment: @Haboryme how should i add an interval in such a situation where i am subtracting time?

Comment: Do: `lakers$time <-as.numeric(dminutes(c(12, 24, 36, 48, 53)[lakers$period]) - lakers$time)`

Comment: @Haboryme i have tried it but it does not produces the desired output. i have attached the link to the output required

Comment: I do get the same shape as your histogram, though the peaks are not as high (less than 850).

Comment: @Haboryme yes,same is the case is with mine but the histogram in image is quite accurate as i am trying to generate results of a published paper so is there any possibility to produce a duplicate of the image?

Comment: Actually, the answer lies in the choice of bindwidth. Higher bindwidths (70-80) produce plots closer to the one you showed.

Comment: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=awy5vrAE In the r-fiddle environment it produces the proper result. Locally, I also get a different shape - so perhaps there are inconsistencies between different package version. Using sessionInfo() r-fiddle tells me it uses ggplot2_0.9.3.1 and lubridate_1.3.3, locally I run ggplot2_2.2.0.9000 and lubridate_1.5.6

Comment: @CMichael thanks that really helped. if i had to produce the same results on the latest version of R studio using latest packages similar to what you mentioned. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used as.numeric and converted both classes to numeric classes using an older version of R studio